# OBIEE12C - Allowed operations in XML writeback file

Tags: stored-procedures, obiee

I would like to know if it is possible to include sql operations on the XML writeback template other than insert and update.
Would it be possible to call a database stored procedure?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OBIEE and its current incarnation OAS (OBIEE has been replaced since some years now) are analytical platform tools. They are not data entry or data generation tools.
That's what tings like APEX are for. It's free, it's part of the DB and you can just embed it into OBI/OAS. It also does all the checks, validations, field type enforcement, business rules etc that OBI/OAS will never do.
You're trying to use the wrong tool for your requirement. Take 2 steps back and look at the bigger picture.

Comment: Thank you Chris. Never heard of APEX. I will investigate it.